# Prevent browser from becoming non-responsive during reflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm using a javascript function to add very large nested tables to a site. I've managed to optimize the javascript itself so it runs quite quickly, however the browser tends to hang during reflows (often for 5-10 seconds), as it's not uncommon for 50 MB of HTML to be added in each go. There is only a single reflow event, but it would be preferable to remove this non-responsive period.

Is it possible to have reflow events run in the background, or would it be simpler to have child tables default to `display: none` and have a button to display them?

Code will be posted as necessary.

AJAX request:

```
function getResult(command,server) { 
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST",baseCommand.concat(server).concat(basePath).concat(command),false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        result=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        return result;
}
```

Code used to build site:

```
function buildTabs() {
        var tabsString="";
        //Formatting and such here
        for (var i in commands) {
            tabsString=tabsString.concat(buildTab(commands[i]));
        }
        //A bit more formatting
        document.getElementById('tabsTable').innerHTML=tabsString;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered pagination? Or something like what google images does (load as you scroll).

Comment: Post the code which makes AJAX request. Also tell us if you fetch HTML from the server or just the data and then you build DOM part with JS?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Only a JSON string is fetched from the server - I build the DOM with JS. I'll post the code for the AJAX request in the main body, though it only takes about 2 seconds for larger tables.

Comment: Then AJAX is not a problem. Are you immediately adding new elements to the document or building the entire DOM part and append it when it's ready?

Comment: Yeah, I've used Firefox's profiler to confirm that reflow is causing the majority of the hang time - it usually takes about twice as long as the rest of the process.

Comment: @tcooc I've considered pagination/infinite scrolling, but how would that work for when I have two tables in parallel for comparing purposes?

Comment: @Larkeith How would pagination prevent tables from being comparable? Also, can you include the code used to generate the html elements.

Comment: @tcooc I'm sort of unclear as to how one would break the pages without cutting off the second table - the format currently is `<table style='float:left;'>blahblahblah</table><table style='float:right'>asdfasdfasdf</table>`. Which code do you want? The code that builds the actual tables, or the one that adds it to the HTML?

Comment: 50MB of HTML will always give you performance problems.

Comment: But why do you create an HTML string in JS and assign it to `innerHTML` instead of using DOM manipulation methods??? You force the browser to parse a very long HTML. That's not the way to go. `appendChild` and `createElement` are your friends. @DanMan exactly :)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Wait, does that slow down the browser? I had for some reason assumed it was of equal efficiency. If that's the issue, could you add it to your answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: _“but how would that work for when I have two tables in parallel for comparing purposes?”_ – how does that work _at all_ as you have implemented it now? Let’s assume only half of those 50MB is code, the rest data – who wants to compare 25MB worth of text(?) data on-screen in one go …? Sounds to me like your site is actually more broken from an UX point of view then from the actual rendering time problem …

Comment: @Larkeith __YES__ it slows down the browser like __!#@!__ I'm surprised it doesn't kill your browser... _Answer edited._

Comment: @CBroe There are lots of sorting and hiding options to allow the users to view and compare parts of the table; the reason rendering time was such an issue is that most of the data has to updated quite frequently, and as such having 10s of latency would be unacceptable.

Comment: #ElmoVanKielmo That does seem to be the issue - Thanks for the successful fix! A side note - if you have it set to refresh every five seconds on the innerHTML method, this most definitely _does_ kill your browser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using this kind of pattern:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container_id');
// Container is an already existing and visible DOM node which holds tables
var result = getResult(command, server);
var table = document.createElement('table');
container.appendChild(table);
// Here comes the big nested for-loop
// which fills the table with results from AJAX call
```

This way you force the browser to recalculate cell sizes and redraw the table each time you add new row. This hurts your browser.

Instead fill the table while it's not yet attached to the document. This way calculations and redraw will be done only once. The correct pattern is something like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container_id');
// Container is an already existing and visible DOM node which holds tables
var result = getResult(command, server);
var table = document.createElement('table');
// Here comes the big nested for-loop
// which fills the table with results from AJAX call
container.appendChild(table);
```

**EDIT:** While the above is still true, the real problem is the wrong way of modifying DOM tree. We don't build a huge HTML string and assign it to `innerHTML` attribute of some element. We use `DOM manipulation methods`.

Example:

```
function buildTabs(nested_array){
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    // Also use CSS classes to do formatting - not inline styles
    table.addClass('my_table_class');
    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    for (var i in nested_array){
        var row = nested_array[i];
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j in row){
            var cell = row[j];
            td = document.createElement('td');
            text_node = document.createTextNode(cell);
            td.appendChild(text_node);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    document.getElementById('tabsTable').appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: I've already reduced it to a single reflow event - I used a similar method as the second one you described, with a function to create the table then appending the entire table at once. It seems to be the size of the change that causes the issue, rather than the number of events. I'll add the code to the question.

Comment: Note that another part of the performance issue is concatenating up to (I'm assuming) 50MB of string data in a loop god knows how many times. You're basically making a copy of the 50MB string and throwing it away every loop.

Comment: @tcooc I'm not making a copy of string. What do you mean?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I think he meant to reply to me

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I was just adding onto your solution with the fact that another serious performance problem is the use of string concats.